# How can I plot NaN values as a special color with imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, nan, colormap, imshow

I am trying to use imshow in matplotlib to plot data as a heatmap, but some of the values are NaNs. I'd like the NaNs to be rendered as a special color not found in the colormap.

example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
a = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5)).astype(float)
a[3,:] = np.nan
ax.imshow(a, interpolation='nearest')
f.canvas.draw()
```

The resultant image is unexpectedly all blue (the lowest color in the jet colormap).  However, if I do the plotting like this:

```
ax.imshow(a, interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=24)
```

--then I get something better, but the NaN values are drawn the same color as vmin... Is there a graceful way that I can set NaNs to be drawn with a special color (eg: gray or transparent)?

Comment: A few years later (`matplotlib.__version__=='1.2.1'`), this works without a problem.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

With newer versions of Matplotlib, it is not necessary to use a masked array anymore.

For example, let’s generate an array where every 7th value is a NaN:

```
arr = np.arange(100, dtype=float).reshape(10, 10)
arr[~(arr % 7).astype(bool)] = np.nan
```

[`.cm.get_cmap()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.get_cmap) is replaced by `.colormaps.get_cmap('viridis')` in `matplotlib v3.7.0`

Set the color with [`.set_bad`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_bad).

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(100, dtype=float).reshape(10, 10)
arr[~(arr % 7).astype(bool)] = np.nan

cmap = mpl.colormaps.get_cmap('viridis')  # viridis is the default colormap for imshow
cmap.set_bad(color='red')

plt.imshow(arr, cmap=cmap)
```

[image: plot result]

---

#### `.cm.get_cmap()` is deprecated

We can modify the current colormap and plot the array with the following lines:

```
current_cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap()
current_cmap.set_bad(color='red')
plt.imshow(arr)
```

Comment: is it possible to use 0 instead of np.nan?

Comment: @yukashimahuksay: yes, but you would need to mask these values. Eg. `arr = np.ma.array(arr, mask=(arr == 0))`.

Answer (score 98):

Hrm, it appears I can use a masked array to do this:

```
masked_array = np.ma.array (a, mask=np.isnan(a))
cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet
cmap.set_bad('white',1.)
ax.imshow(masked_array, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
```

This should suffice, though I'm still open to suggestions. :]

Comment: It definitely does the trick. Official docs show nothing more.

Comment: A side point - I think doing this will override the default `matplotlib.cm.jet`, so I usually make a copy: `import copy; cmap=copy.copy(matplotlib.cm.jet)`.  Also, if you want to set 0-values to a different color, something like `cmap._init(); cm._lut[:,0] = (1,1,1,1)` should work.

Comment: There is also `set_over` and `set_under` to control the coloring of out of range values. The default behaviour is to match the top/bottom of the color range.

Comment: It is not entirely obvious that `'w'` means white. Maybe you could replace `'w'` with `'white'`, so that it is more obvious that you could replace it, for example, with `'red'`? And explain the second parameter to `set_bad`? Apologies to make suggestions to such an old answer, but this would be helpful.

Comment: Is the `masked_array` required at all? If `a` contains NaN values (so it seems as `mask=np.isnan(a)`), then just `imshow`-ing the array `a` with the customized map `cmap` will display NaN-cells with the required colour (white). So it works for me. Are there any exceptions?

Comment: @MaciekS , when using a diverging colormap, you do not want your `nan` values and median values being plotted the same color e.g. white.