# making NaNs into a different colour on colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a similar problem to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578752/how-can-i-plot-nan-values-as-a-special-color-with-imshow-in-matplotlib) and I have tried the solution offered in this post, yet when I run the code I get the following error:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 3785
>      warnings.warn("Warning: converting a masked element to nan.")
>   UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.

Does anyone know what causes this and how I can fix it?
If required I can post my code, but I should warn everyone that it is dependent on data read in from a text file.

Comment: the code from the linked question works just fine for me. Would you show your exact code, and the version of the matplotlib you're using?

Comment: I think I found the problem in my code.  I was masking the values before performing interpolation, however I should interpolate and then mask the values.