# Matplotlib.Colors.LogNorm problems with zeros in 2D-plots when saving to eps

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, eps

In my python program I plot some 2D graphs with imshow:

```
img=imshow(data,
           interpolation='none',
           vmin=0.0001,
           vmax=0.01,
           cmap=custom_map,
           norm=LogNorm()
           )
```

When I save the plot as *.eps or *.pdf I get some strange lines in the pictures, where the values of `data` are very close to `vmin`.

When I save the plot as *.png or *.svg or *.jpg this error doesn't occur.

How can I avoid that python draws this strange lines?

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is a minimal code which should reproduce the problem. At least I get the error all the times...

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

A=np.array([[0.000000,0.000426],[0.000000,0.000524]], dtype=np.float)
pl.imshow(A, interpolation='none', norm=LogNorm())

pl.savefig('test.eps')
pl.savefig('test.png')
```

Even if you do not use `LogNorm()` but use `np.log(A)` the problem occurs in the output.

**Edit 2**
With

```
A=np.array([[np.log(0),np.log(0),np.log(0.1),np.log(0.000426)],
        [np.log(0),np.log(0),np.log(0),np.log(0.000524)]], dtype=np.float)
```

the problem occurs only at the borders from np.log(0) to some real values as you can see in the next picture

[image]

Comment: does your custom map have alpha in it? See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2473.  From the code you gave here there is no way to reproduce your problem (and hence sort out what your problem is).   Please post a _minimal_ amount of code which will reproduce the problem.  _Most_ matplotlib problems can be reproduced with < 15 LoC.

Comment: To be honest, I can't reproduce the problem with any analyticval function which should fit to the shown pattern.... I tried several things: No `vmin` and `vmax`, no `LogNorm`, no `cmap`... the problem occurs only when saving to .eps and .pdf. When the picture is opened in `spyder` after the `pl.show()`-line, there are no black lines. So the error occurs when saving the file!? EDIT: my custom map has no alpha in it.

Comment: The thing you see on the screen is probably rendered through Agg, the ps and pdf paths use two entirely different (vector based) code paths (backends).  This is why getting a simple reproducible example is important.  Also, what version of mpl are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I added a piece of code with which my problem is reproducable... I use version 1.3.1 of mpl and PyCharm as IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a problem with LogNorm() and the zeros in the array... So the bad pixels should have a special colorvalue which can be manually set. For the people who are looking for answers: here is a description: [How can I plot NaN values as a special color with imshow in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578752/how-can-i-plot-nan-values-as-a-special-color-with-imshow-in-matplotlib?rq=1)

Now change the code in the opening post:

```
cmap = matplotlib.cm.jet
cmap.set_bad('w',1.)
pl.imshow(A, interpolation='none', cmap=cmap, norm=LogNorm())
```

With this the eps output is correct - or better: as wanted.

If there are some other ideas, please add them to the comments or answers.

[image]