# Different handling of NaN and -9999.0 in numpy array when plotting

Tags: python, numpy, nan, imshow

I've got a numpy array containing both np.nan (missing value) and -9999.0 (or any other arbitrary value=> non calculation possible), e.g.:

```
arr = array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  nan,  4.,  4.],
   [ 3.,  -9999.0,  2.,  1.,  1.,  4.],
   [ nan,  -9999.0,  3.,  1.,  2.,  1.]])
```

Now I want to plot this array with the `plt.imshow` function. All NaNs shall be transparent/white and all -9999.0s shall be black, for example.
I already tried to mask the array and then use `set_bad` for the colormap. Beyond that, I used `vmin/vmax` and `cm.set_under`.
However, in the first case it yields:
    RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
when I try to mask out all values <9990.
In the second case, obviously both the NaNs and -9999.0s are interepreted as below the range of the depicted range of values.
Does anyone know help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution is to use BOTH `set_under` and `set_bad`:

```
cm.set_bad('white')
cmap.set_under('black')
```

The bad value takes care of the NaNs, the `set_under` sets an extra value for the -9999.0s.

Thanks anyhow for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

It sounded like you said [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2578873/673173) didn't work for you, but it seemed to work for me. From an ipython notebook cell:

```
% matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  np.nan,  4.,  4.],
   [ 3.,  -9999.0,  2.,  1.,  1.,  4.],
   [ np.nan,  -9999.0,  3.,  1.,  2.,  1.]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
masked_array = np.ma.array (a, mask=np.isnan(a))
cmap = matplotlib.cm.autumn
cmap.set_bad('w',1.)
ax.imshow(masked_array, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
```

[imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI5Q8.jpg) since it won't let me post images due to low rep.

Comment: This works, however, I think it does not consider an extra value for the -9999.0. It simply integrates it into the colormap range.

Comment: Ah, sorry, got thrown off the scent by "All NaNs shall be transparent/white and all -9999.0s shall be black, for example." Read it too quickly. Glad it looks like you figured it out.

Comment: Thanks neverthless! :-)