# A few related questions about matplotlib.pyplot.matshow and np matrix objects: plotting "None"/"nan", and x axis offset

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

Let's say I have the following matrix (as a `numpy.matrix` or `np.array` object):

```
#x/column labels: = -1, 0, 1

#y/row labels: 0, 1, 2 (like normal)

data: np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [-1, np.nan, -2], [7, -5, -6]])

plt.matshow(data, colorbar = 'RdBu')

plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

I want to use `plt.matshow()` on this matrix. First, I don't know why, but sometimes, my `np.matrix` objects display like this if I simply print them out (just ignore that the numbers are slightly different, please):

```
matrix([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
    [-1., nan, -2.],
    [-3.,  5.,  2.]])
```

These will be accepted by `np.matshow()`. However sometimes they appear like this:

```
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
    [-1, nan, -2],
    [7, -5, -6]], dtype=object)
```

First question:

If that `dtype=object` is there, `np.matshow()` will not plot them if a `nan` or `None` is present. I don't know why this tag is there sometimes and sometimes not. I generate these through a somewhat convoluted script, and I suspect it may be sometimes because I am doing `np.matrix(a)` where `a` is some python array or `np.array`. Could that be the cause? I have played around with simple cases in terminal windows but have not been able to figure it out. Sometimes the "error marker" is `np.nan`, sometimes it's python's `None`.

Second question:
When there is a `np.nan` in the matrix, `matshow()` just paints that square white. This is okay if the color map used, like the default one, does not include white. However, I want to use a "binary" type color scale like `RdBu`; positive for blue, negative for red, white for 0. Is there a way to, for example, put a big green X over `nan`'s, or make its square black, etc? Basically, a way to clearly distinguish `nan`'s from 0's in this color map.

Third question: please notice in my first code snipped that the x/column labels are supposed to be `-1, 0, 1`. Since the `np.matrix` object seems to not have custom indices, it just plots starting from `0`. Is there a way to pass this info to `np.matshow`? If I use `plt.xlim([-1, 1])` for example, it just only shows two of the rows of the matrix, since there is no data at `-1`, and the third row is at `x = 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial solution to your question: Similar problem (the colormap thing) has been partially addressed here: [How can I plot NaN values as a special color with imshow in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578752/how-can-i-plot-nan-values-as-a-special-color-with-imshow-in-matplotlib) ... Specifically for your array, it would be as follows where you can choose any color `nan_color` you like to plot the `nan` values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data =  np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [-1, np.nan, -2], [7, -5, -6]])
data_masked = np.ma.array(data, mask=np.isnan(data))
nan_color = 'black' # or 'white' or whatever you like
color = cm.RdBu
color.set_bad(nan_color,1.)
plt.matshow(data_masked, cmap=color)
plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: Your "here" link seems to not work, but thanks for the code snip, I'll try it out.

Comment: I don't know why hyperlink wasn't working but I edited with the complete link

Answer (score 1):

You can first make your return a numpy float array like this:

```
data = np.array(data).astype(np.float)
```