# NaN values as special color in pyplot scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have an (x,y)-scatter plot, where each point is associated with a color. Some points, however, do not have a valid color, and are assigned NaN. I would like to include these points, but show them in a color not contained by the colormap.

Here's the example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcol
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numPoints = 20
nanFrequency = 3
xVec = np.arange(numPoints, dtype=float)
yVec = xVec
colorVec = np.linspace(0,1,numPoints)
colorVec[range(0, numPoints, nanFrequency)] = np.nan

colormap = mcol.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Blue-Red-Colormap", ["b", "r"])

plt.scatter(xVec, yVec, c=colorVec, cmap=colormap)
```

and the corresponding output:
[image: Scatter plot not showing points with invalid color]

Every third point is not shown due to its invalid color value. Based on my code, I would have expected these points to be shown in yellow. Why doesn't this work?

Note that there's a [related post concerning imshow()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649061/2918960), from which the above code is inspired. The solution presented there does not seem to work for me.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your `NaN` values are not plotted is that matplotlib's scatter currently filters them out before giving them to the colormap.

To show the `NaN` entries you can manually assign them a dummy value with a special meaning. For example, because your list is in the range `[0, 1]` you could define that any value `> 1` get a special color. For this you will have to fix the range of the color-axis, and specify a color for entries outside this range (in this case higher than the maximum).

Basically you will use:

```py
cax = ax.scatter(...)
cax.cmap.set_over('y') # assigns yellow to any entry >1
cax.set_clim(0, 1)     # fixes the range of 'normal' colors to (0, 1)
```

For your example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numPoints = 20
nanFrequency = 3
xVec = np.arange(numPoints, dtype=float)
yVec = xVec
colorVec = np.linspace(0,1,numPoints)
colorVec[range(0, numPoints, nanFrequency)] = np.NaN

cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Blue-Red-Colormap", ["b", "r"], numPoints)

# ---

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(8, 2*6))

# ---

ax = axes[0]

ax.scatter(xVec, yVec, c=colorVec, cmap=cmap)

ax.set_xlim([0, 20])
ax.set_ylim([0, 20])

# ---

ax = axes[1]

colorVec[np.isnan(colorVec)] = 2.0

cax = ax.scatter(xVec, yVec, c=colorVec, cmap=cmap)
cax.cmap.set_over('y')
cax.set_clim(0, 1)

ax.set_xlim([0, 20])
ax.set_ylim([0, 20])

# ---

plt.show()
```

Which produces two subplots: the top corresponds to what you had, the bottom uses the dummy value and assigns yellow to it:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Of course you need to set the desired yellow to your colormap, `colormap.set_bad("yellow")`.

Then, this is a long standing bug in matplotlib ([#4354](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4354)), which fortunately has now been fixed ([#12422](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12422)).

So from matplotlib 3.1 onwards, you can use the `plotnonfinite=True` argument to include masked or invalid points in scatter plots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcol
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numPoints = 20
nanFrequency = 3
xVec = np.arange(numPoints, dtype=float)
yVec = xVec
colorVec = np.linspace(0,1,numPoints)
colorVec[range(0, numPoints, nanFrequency)] = np.nan

colormap = mcol.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Blue-Red-Colormap", ["b", "r"])
colormap.set_bad("yellow")

plt.scatter(xVec, yVec, c=colorVec, cmap=colormap, plotnonfinite=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]