# How can I make a transparent background?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, alpha-transparency

I have a .csv file which contains some data where x, y, x1, y1 are the coordinate points, and p is the value.  My below code is working very well for plotting, but when I am plotting the data, I am getting a background color like the purple color. I don't want any color in the background. I want the background will be **Transparent**. My ultimate goal is overlying this result over an image. I am new in Python. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Download link of the .csv file  [here](http://www.filedropper.com/flowerfeature) or [link-2](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=11379631698372073093) or [link-3](https://megaupload.nz/P1A8p5w4n7/flower_feature_csv)**

I am getting below result [image: result]

**My Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from skimage import transform
from PIL import Image
import cv2

x_dim=1200
y_dim=1200

# Read CSV 
df = pd.read_csv("flower_feature.csv")

# Create numpy array of zeros os same size
array = np.zeros((x_dim, y_dim), dtype=np.uint8)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    x = np.int(row["x"])
    y = np.int(row["y"])
    x1 = np.int(row["x1"])
    y1 = np.int(row["y1"])
    p = row["p"]
    array[x:x1,y:y1] = p

map = ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(array, sigma=16)
plt.imshow(map)
plt.show()
```

**As per Ghassen's suggestion I am getting below results. I am still not getting the transparent background.**

When Alpha =0

[image: alpha=0]

When alpha =0.5

[image: alpha =0.5]

When alpha =1

[image: alpha=1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code  :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


x_dim=1200
y_dim=1200

# Read CSV 
df = pd.read_csv("/home/rosafi/Downloads/flower_feature.csv")

# Create numpy array of zeros os same size
array = np.ones((x_dim, y_dim), dtype=np.uint8)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    x = np.int(row["x"])
    y = np.int(row["y"])
    x1 = np.int(row["x1"])
    y1 = np.int(row["y1"])
    p = row["p"]
    array[x:x1,y:y1] = p

map = ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(array, sigma=16)
map = np.ma.masked_where(map == 0, map)
plt.imshow(map)
plt.show()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried in this way too. When alpha = 0, I am getting nothing. I changed the value of alpha to 0.5 or up to 1. When I am overlaying that image I am not getting background of the image.

Comment: When you set alpha to 0 the background desapeare totaly with the curve of data?  I can't download the csv file but i test alpha with 0 there is no bckground and with one it's the same as your image

Comment: I have updated the results when alpha=0, 0.5 and 1. Please check my edited question. I also updated .csv file download link. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think we should find how to make background transparent in this stage map = ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(array, sigma=16) in the application of gaussian filter

Comment: @Js541 try with this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578752/how-can-i-plot-nan-values-as-a-special-color-with-imshow-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by masking out the values where values ==0. The code will be

`from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable`

`masked_data = np.ma.masked_where(map == 0, map)`